# How to create controller spec to test unauthorized access, redirect and message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, cancan

I am trying to create controller specs, in this case for a user who is not authorized to access this resource. I need to detect the status, location of redirect, and message from Devise/ Cancan.

After much hacking away, I came up with this.

```
context 'with unauthorized user' do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    subject { xhr :get, :index, {} }
    it { subject; response.status.should eq 401 } #successfully detects unauthorized
    it { should redirect_to new_user_session_path } #Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <401>
    it 'redirects' do 
      get :index, {}
      expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path) #successfully detects redirect
      # how to get the Devise message?
    end
  end
end
```

Could someone please help me to understand what is happening here.

1. What is the difference between `xhr :get, :index` and `get :index,
   {}`.
2. What is the difference between `subject; response.status.should eq
   401` and `response.status.should eq 401'
3. How to I get the message from the response?

Answer (score 2):

Controller specs stubs many layers of the application. For example they don't actually create a HTTP request or go through the routing layer. Also they do not render views by default. This makes the tests somewhat faster but the stubbing does has a cost in terms in test acuity.

`get :foo` creates a request object that fakes a HTTP request. Rails does this by looking at your routes and trying to find something that matches the params. `xhr :foo` does about the same but sets the request headers up so it appears to be a XHR request.

The **redirect_to** matcher tests that the response is HTTP redirect. That means that the response code should be in the 300-399 range and contain a location header.

To test other response codes you should instead do something like:

```
context 'with unauthorized user' do  
  describe 'GET #index' do
    before { get :index }
    subject { response }
    it { is_expected.to have_http_status 401 } 
    it "redirects to login" do
      expect(response.headers[:location]).to equal new_user_session_path
    end
  end
end
```

#### How to I get the message from the response?

The easy answer is that you use `render_views` in the context which will give you the body in `response.body`. However this will not work as you think since the redirect is not actually followed.

Consider using a feature spec to test this behavior instead:

```
RSpec.feature "Foos" do
  context "A guest" do
    scenario "should not be able to view all Foos" do
      visit "/foos"
      expect(response).to have_content "You are not allowed to view this page"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: On a side note - don't use the global monkeypatch `.should` method. It has been depreachiated for a long time since it leads to false positives and is just a generally bad idea. Also your use of `it` blocks is very idiosyncratic. If you want to write one-liners with `its(:foo) { should eq 'bar' }` syntax you should try the `rspec-its` gem.